# An extended warranty pays a benefit of $100$ if failure occurs between time $t = 1.5$ and $t = 8$. Find $P(w<79)$.

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

> The time until failure, $T$, of a product is modeled by a uniform distribution on $[0, 10]$. An
>   extended warranty pays a benefit of $100$ if failure occurs between time $t = 1.5$ and $t = 8$.
>   The present value, $W$, of this benefit is
>   $$w(t)=\begin{cases}
> {0} & \text{if } 0\leq t<1.50\\
> 100e^{-0.04} & \text{if } 1.5\leq t< 8.0,\\
> 0 & \text{if } 8\leq t\leq 10,\end{cases}$$

\begin{align*}
P(w<79) &= p(100 e^{-.04t}<79)\\
&= p(t>5.89)\\
&= 1-p(t<5.89)\\
&= 1-F(5.89)\\
&= 1-.589\\
&= 0.411
\end{align*}

correct answer is $0.59$

Comment: Please review my edits and use them as a model for your future posts. Some of your notation was not clear.

Comment: $P(W<79)=P(W<79|T\in [0,1.5])P(T\in [0,1.5])+P(W<79|T\in [1.5,8])P(T \in [1.5,8])+P(W<79|T\in[8,10])P(Ti\in[8,10])$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

$$P(W<79)=P(W<79|T\in [0,1.5])P(T\in [0,1.5])+P(W<79|T\in [1.5,8])P(T \in [1.5,8])+P(W<79|T\in[8,10])P(T\in[8,10])$$

Answer (score 0):

You must consider the conditional CDF of W under all three conditions on T. 
First, since W=0 for T in [0,1.5], then:

Pr(W<79| 0

Secondly, since W= 100exp(-.04t) for T in [1.5,8], then:

Pr(W<79|1.5 < T < 8)=.411 as you calculated above

Lastly, since W=0 for T in [8,10],then:

Pr(W<79|8 < T < 10)=Pr(0<79| 0 < T < 10)=1

The CDF of a a mixed distribution like W, which is weighted based on values of T in the form:

Pr(W <= 79)=Pr( W <= 79 | 0 < T < 1.5) Pr(0 < T < 1.5) + Pr(W<= 79| 1.5 < T < 8) Pr( 1.5 < T < 8) + Pr( W <= 79 | 8 < T < 10) Pr(8 < T < 10)

The weights on the conditional CDF distributions, which are based on probabilities in T, are calculated from the PDF of the continuous uniform distribution on [0,10]. For example,

Pr(0 < T < 1.5) =(1.5)/10= 3/20

and so on...

You can then plug these values into the above conditional CDF form to get the correct answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please format your answer using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)